# Flashed BTU from sammobile but is still EVR

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I'm trying to flash BTU stock firmware from sammobile for my s9 g960f. I got the firmware from here https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s9/SM-G960F/BTU/  date: 14/11/18 pda: G960FXXS2BRJ6.

I used Odin to install the firmware, it appared to work from odin and the phone restated and went straight to android setup, but is started to install EE apps and is showing as EVR crc in software info. Could this an error on my end or not the right files on sammobile?

Comment: By the way, since Odin isn't an official tool or supported and its internals are not well known, I'd recommend [Heimdall](https://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/). Here is an article on how to [flash ROMs with Heimdall on an S9](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/starlte/install). Simply switch out the files for whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is an error on your end or Sammobiles. You did however appear to have flashed EVR firmware variant instead of Blu firmware variant.

[image: IMG:]

Carefully check and re-download the Blu firmware variant and flash again through Odin.

Thinking about it though, as long as the CSC you are changing it from is not included in the CSC you are flashing, otherwise it will just default back to the phones original CSC.

You will need to flash CSC and not HOME_CSC in order to change though, which will reset the phone back to factory.

If the problem persists, contact Sammobile customer support to inform them of issue.

Comment: So i want to replace the firmware with unbranded stock firmware, to do this i not only have to replace AP in odin but also CSC? (never replaced csc before). If my phone is locked to EE, would this have any effect on this process?

Comment: Some definitions: The CSC  (Consumer Software Customization) is: It is specific to geographical region and carriers. It contains the software packages specific to that region, carrier branding and APN setting.
PDA: It refers to the build version of the software or firmware. PDA is now known as AP in the latest versions of Odin.
First question the answer would be Yes. The AP is replaced every time new updated firmware is flashed. Really the only oddball change would be the CSC (carrier branding stuffs) the CSC file should be in the BTU download you have Not HOME_CSC.

Comment: Second question, define locked to EE? Like carrier network locked can only be used on that carriers network? My answer would be I don't know. When I messed around with re-branding it was with a network unlocked t-mobile s6.

Comment: Just reflashed with CSC (not the Home one) and the phone now says its `XEU/XEU/EVR`. I read that XEU is the same thing as BTU but still showing EVR. Happen to know if this is correct for stock firmware? also yeah carrier locked to EE.